# Full-height CSS layout, with multiple columns

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a layout that is working, but it has one very annoying problem.. when the content is taller than the screen, the background stops.

This is the desired layout in bad-ASCII-art format:

```
_____________________  _
|    | long    |logo|   |
|    | content |    |   |
|    |         |    |   |
|    |         |    |   |
|grad|         |grad|   | Viewport
|    |         |    |   |
|    |         |    |   |
|    |         |    |  _|
|    |         |    |
|    |         |    |
_____________________

|2em| <-20em->| 2em|
```

..or with short content..

```
_____________________  _
|    | short   |logo|   |
|    | content |    |   |
|    |         |    |   |
|    |         |    |   |
|grad|         |grad|   | Viewport
|    |         |    |   |
|    |         |    |   |
|    |         |    |   |
|    |         |    |   |
_____________________  _|
```

Basically it looks like a single column, with a glow as a column either side. Over the left-glow is a logo. When the content is short, it is still the full-height.

I have tried using the [CSS min-height hack](http://www.dustindiaz.com/min-height-fast-hack/), which fixes the middle column, but then the gradients only extend as far as the content (in the left column, a single `&nbsp;`, in the right column the logo)

---

Here is what the layout looks like:

[image: Layout]

And the problem (when the browser window is shrunk vertically):

[image: Problem]

Finally, the problem HTML/CSS, http://data.dbrweb.co.uk/tmp/fifestock_layout_problem/

Comment: Could you post the actual html page so we can tweak and test?

Comment: Sure, I've added it into the post - the address is.. http://data.dbrweb.co.uk/tmp/fifestock_layout_problem/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that you have your gradients in seperate columns to the left and right, you need to implement "**[faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/)**".

If you're after elastic versions, have a look at [**Elastic Faux Columns**](http://nickcowie.com/2005/elastic-faux-columns/) and [**Multi-Column Layouts Climb Out of the Box**](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlayouts).

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I ended up using, using [this technique](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61) of high value for `padding-bottom`, with an equal but inverted value in `margin-bottom` - then you set `overflow:hidden` on the div enclosing that huge margin.

It's rather hackish, but it works! I now have a full-height, a single em-defined width, and a full-height background-image down each side! There's not much extra markup (a container div, a div for each of the three columns)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Yay</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body, html{
            height:100%;
            margin:0;
            background:#1d4b76;
        }
        #contain{
            width:40em;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        #left{
            background-image:url("static/grad_left.png");
            background-repeat:repeat-y;
            background-position:right;

            height:100%;
            float:left;
            width:150px;

            padding-bottom:10000px;
            margin-bottom:-10000px;
        }
        #middle{
            float:left;
            background:#000;
            color:#fff;
            width:20em;

            padding-bottom:100000px;
            margin-bottom:-100000px;
        }
        #right{
            float:left;
            background-image:url("static/grad_right.png");
            background-repeat:repeat-y;
            background-position:left;
            width:150px;

            padding-bottom:100000px;
            margin-bottom:-100000px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contain">
        <div id="left">
            &nbsp;              
        </div>
        <div id="middle">
                    Put lots of text here
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <img src="static/logo.png" width="150" height="150" alt="Logo">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just watched a video about [YUI's grids](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/) and looked very promising (recommended watching!). I haven't had the time to test it out, yet, but most probably will do so in the future. It  might be what you want.

Comment: I looked into the YUI stuff, but it doesn't seem quite flexible enough - I could only workout how to have ~700px, ~900px and 100% width columns?

Comment: That is true, there were some predefined column widths. But you are free to modify the values to suit your needs, naturally...

Answer (score 1):

Try with this modifications:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Test page</title>
 <style type="text/css" media="screen">
   html, body{
     margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
     padding:0;
     width:22em;
   }

   #wrapper{
      background-color:#ccc;
   }

   #left{
      float:left;
      width:22em;
      background-color:#00f;
    }

    #middle{
       float:right;
       width:18em;
       margin-right:2em;
       background-color:#f00;
     }

     #right{
        float: right;
        width:20em;
        background-color:#0f0;
        background-image: url(static/logo.png);
        background-position: top right;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }

   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id="wrapper">
       <div id="left">
          <div id="right">
             <div id="middle">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br><br><br> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<br><br><br>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br><br><br> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in oluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<br><br><br>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br><br><br>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<br><br><br>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this after `<div id="right">...</div>`:

```
<div style="clear: both; font-size: 1px; line-height:1px">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got there in the end with this one, but had to make a few changes to your markup and the images.

1. Remove the #left and #right divs.
2. Make a new single background image that's 592px wide, transparent background and has the gradients at the left and right of it - a 1px high image with left gradient - transparent section 504px wide - right gradient.
3. Add the logo to the #wrapper, just before the #middle

So the markup looks like this now:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <img src="static/fifestock_logo.png" />
        <div id="middle">
        ... etc ...
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then, the relevant changes in the stylesheet are:

```
#wrapper{
    height:100%;
    width:805px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align: right;
}

#middle {
    width:504px;
    padding: 0 44px;
    margin: -154px auto 0 auto;
    background:#000 url(new_bg.png) repeat-y top left;
}
```

Looks fine to me.

Only tested in in FF3 and Opera (running Linux without access to Windows / Mac atm) but I don't think there should be any big issues with it in IE / Opera.

Comment: I think dbr wants a liquid desing, so you can't use fixed width in pixels. But, if fixed width is acceptable, your solution is OK and more clean.