# How to write this in a more sophisticated way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This works, but I'm sure that it written more cleanly.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.col').css({'height':($(document).height())+'px'});
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('.col').css({'height':($(document).height())+'px'});
  });
}
</script>
```

I've tried without the first `$('.col').css...` and it doesn't work.
So basically what would I like to tell the browser is: "When document is ready, resize this div, and keep on resizing it on every height change".

Comment: I don't see any way to significantly simplify the JS.  You could explore CSS solutions.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289409/full-height-css-layout-with-multiple-columns and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239534/how-to-have-multiple-columns-that-consume-100-height-using-twitter-bootstrap.

Comment: performance can be improved if you only trigger resize when the width changes

Answer (score 3):

Here it is:

```
<script>
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('.col').css({'height':($(document).height())+'px'});
    });
    $(function(){
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    });
</script>
```

You can listen to the `resize` event and trigger it when the document is ready.

Other small changes:

- you can simplify `document.ready` with `$(function(){})`
- the resize event listener could be created before `document.ready`, because the `window` object is always present and you can attach events to it as early as you need.

Answer (score 2):

Or another variation, with a little bit (I guess) cleaner syntax:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.col').height($(document).height());
}).resize();
```