# What's the best way to have two columns/divs have matched height no mater what the content length is in either div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here's a jsfiddle example of doing it with css, They'll match at any length. But I need it to at minimum be the full height of the viewport/body. In this example, it cuts short when there's only a little content:

http://jsfiddle.net/4C89C/5/

I'm not sure what else is possible in css. I'm thinking some sort of javascript div height matching is needed. Really, any solution would work for me, even if it's complicated.

Thanks,

Here's the code from the fiddle:

```
<style>
html, body { height:100%; }
#content {
border:thin solid red;
}

#innerdiv {
height:100%;
float:left;
background-color: #eee;
width: 60%;
}

#innerdiv2 {
height:100%;
float:right;
background-color: blue;
width: 40%;
}
#textdiv {
height: 100%;
padding-left: 40px;
display:table;
}
#textdiv2 {
height: 100%;
padding-left: 40px;
color: white;
}
</style>

    <div id="content">
<div id="innerdiv">
    <div id="textdiv">Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />

    </div>
</div>
<div id="innerdiv2">
    <div id="textdiv2">Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br />Filler<br /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try looking at the solution in this Stack Overflow article.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289409/full-height-css-layout-with-multiple-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you two good ways to do this; the one you choose will depend on your preference and how you want it to look.

---

### CSS Solution

One way to ensure that two divs will have the same height regardless of content in CSS is to manipulate the `height` and `overflow` properties.

By setting both elements to have the same height and giving them either no overflow:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

or giving them scrollable overflow:

```
overflow:auto;
```

You'll ensure that the two divs will have the same predefined height (that you set with `height:...px;`). The first overflow option will simply hide any content that does not fit in the div, while the second will introduce scrollbars in the vertical or horizontal if the content does not fit in the div.

---

### jQuery solution

The other way you can do this would be to use jQuery to calculate the height of the taller div and set both divs to use that height.

For instance:

```
if($("#div1").height() > $("#div2").height())
    $("#div2").height($("#div1").height());
else
    $("#div1").height($("#div2").height());
```

You would  put this in your `$(document).ready()` if the content of these divs will not be modified after the page load, or call it immediately after the content of either div changes.

Comment: Hi, Thanks: I'm going to give your jQuery solution a shot. It's true that I don't need the heights to change after the page loads. My current divs are floated and I'd like a solution that can apply to any divs that I need to match to the longest div. Question: being unfamiliar with the some jQuery, how do I but the code into $(document).ready() exactly? Is it like $(document).ready() {put code here?}

Secondly: do you know if this can work to make the divs heights a minimum of the full length of the viewport/body?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){//put code here});`; the .height() method can be used to get the height of any element. If you want the window, use `$(window).height()`, or `$(document).height()` for the height of the document.

Comment: Thanks again: one more question: if I set it to the height of the window/viewport, and then the user expands the height of the window, will the height of the divs adjust? Or will it remain the original length of the window?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to get this to work. I now just need the div to expand to the full length of the window if it is less than it, but it's not working yet:

     if($("#div1").height() < $(window).height())
    {
        $("#div1").height($("window").height());
    }

Can you see anything I'm doing wrong? Should this work?

Comment: Don't put window in quotes. Just `$(window)`

Answer (score 0):

If you use a parent with display:table; height:100%; and direct child displayd as table-cell; you have it.

If you float them, display is killed, and you loose it.

Other old and solid solution is to use the "faux-colonnes" methodes, wich draws column on parent background, no matter heights of child kept with no background as float or inline-block elements.

(if this seems 'like a comment', then i'll remove it to comments).

There's No need of jquery to just draw 2 columns,  to my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with flexbox: http://jsfiddle.net/4C89C/8/

```
#content {
    border:thin solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

(You'll need to add appropriate vendor prefixes)

Comment: Hi, Do know how to make it a minimum height of the full height of the viewport. In this example with not much text, the columns match, but I need them to at least be as long as the viewport and not stop up where they stop: http://jsfiddle.net/v53X8/

Comment: Take a look at [viewport units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)